# calclulate percentage on values in mysql table and write the percentage value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, shell

hi iam noob in my sql queries. below is my data set

```
+------------+---------+-----------+--+------+--------+
| day_id     | hour_id | user_type |id|Charge| mobile |
+------------+---------+-----------+--+------+--------+
| 2015-07-17 |      20 | Overall   |1 |   30 |     60 |
| 2015-07-17 |      20 | Overall   |2 |  100 |    100 |
| 2015-07-17 |      20 | new       |1 |   20 |     30 |
| 2015-07-17 |      20 | new       |2 |  100 |     60 |
| 2015-07-17 |      21 | Overall   |1 |   10 |     20 |
| 2015-07-17 |      21 | Overall   |2 |    1 |      1 |
| 2015-07-17 |      21 | New       |1 |   10 |     50 |
| 2015-07-17 |      21 | New       |2 |    1 |      2 |
| 2015-07-16 |      20 | Overall   |1 |   60 |     30 |
| 2015-07-16 |      20 | Overall   |2 |   50 |    200 |
| 2015-07-16 |      20 | New       |1 |   40 |     60 |
| 2015-07-16 |      20 | New       |2 |  140 |     30 |
| 2015-07-16 |      21 | Overall   |1 |   14 |     40 |
| 2015-07-16 |      21 | Overall   |2 |    2 |      1 |
| 2015-07-16 |      21 | New       |1 |   14 |    100 |
| 2015-07-16 |      21 | New       |2 |    1 |      4 |
| 2015-07-15 |      20 | Overall   |1 |   60 |     60 |
| 2015-07-15 |      20 | Overall   |2 |   40 |     70 |
+------------+---------+-----------+--+------+--------+
```

now i need to write a query in shell or may be just a sql query so that i can calculate the percentage of value (in column charge and mobile) change compared to 2 days before value (in column charge and mobile)

ie the percentage of change of value from column "charge" and "mobile" where day_id = today ie 2015-07-17, user_type = overall, id=0 to the 1 day old value ie 2015-07-17 from column "charge" and "mobile" where user_type = overall, id=0 
the percent change should be written in different table like this

```
+------------+---------+-----------+--+------+--------+
| day_id     | hour_id | user_type |id|Charge| mobile |
| Today      |         |           |  |Change|Change  |
+------------+---------+-----------+--+------+--------+
| 2015-07-17 |      20 | Overall   |1 | -100 |    100 |
| 2015-07-17 |      20 | Overall   |2 |  100 |   -100 |
| 2015-07-17 |      20 | new       |1 | -100 |      0 |
| 2015-07-17 |      20 | new       |2 |   40 |    100 |
| 2015-07-17 |      21 | Overall   |1 |  -40 |   -100 |
| 2015-07-17 |      21 | Overall   |2 | -100 |      0 |
| 2015-07-17 |      21 | New       |1 |  -40 |   -100 |
| 2015-07-17 |      21 | New       |2 |    0 |   -100 |
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. For `hour_id = 20, user_type = Overall, id = 1`, mobile stayed the same at 60, so why do you have 100% change? And Charge changed from 60 to 30, that should be -50%, not -100%.

Comment: hi thanks for ur comment.

Comment: hi thanks for ur comment. on 2015-07-16 for `hour_id = 20, user_type = Overall, id = 1` charge was 60 and mobile was 30 on 2015-07-17 for `hour_id = 20, user_type = Overall, id = 1` it became charge as 30 and mobile as 60. ie charge was reduced by 100 % were-as mobile was increased by 100%

Comment: You said 2 days before, that's 2015-07-15, not 2015-07-16.

Comment: ohhk actuly i wanted to compare with one week old data. but to make it simple i gave this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this with a self-JOIN:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
SELECT t1.day_id, t1.hour_id, t1.user_type, t1.id, 
        (t1.Charge-t2.Charge)/t2.Charge*100 AS Charge_Change,
        (t1.mobile-t2.mobile)/t2.mobile*100 AS mobile_Change
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.day_id = DATE_ADD(t2.day_id, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    AND t1.hour_id = t2.hour_id AND t1.user_type = t2.user_type
    AND t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: just fixed some type at second last line `t1.user_type - t2.user_type` and changed it to `t1.user_type = t2.user_type` and also removed t1.id as i dont have id column. the script is used was 

`SELECT t1.day_id, t1.hour_id, t1.user_type,
        (t1.Charge-t2.Charge)/t2.Charge*100 AS Charge_Change,
        (t1.mobile-t2.mobile)/t2.mobile*100 AS mobile_Change
FROM fc_hourly_channel_product_stats AS t1
JOIN fc_hourly_channel_product_stats AS t2 ON t1.day_id = DATE_ADD(t2.day_id, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND t1.hour_id = t2.hour_id AND t1.user_type = t2.user_type; `

Comment: when i run this query it displays the result on the screen. what i want is to write whatever is displayed to new table which i specify and the calculation should only be done for todays date id and the hour id and not for entire data. the date id and hour id are created with shell script `day_id=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')` and `hr_id=$(date '+%H')` . thank u so much for ur help

Comment: What's the problem? Just use `CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT ...` or `INSERT INTO new_Table SELECT ...`